# LinearLayout's childview down dislocation

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I code this layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp">

    <TextView
        style="@style/textStyle.Medium.black"
        android:layout_width="79dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center|start"
        android:minHeight="42dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:text="姓名"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        style="@style/textStyle.Medium.subTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center|end"
        android:minHeight="42dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:text="暂无"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

but I set text very long, like:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        style="@style/textStyle.Medium.subTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center|end"
        android:minHeight="42dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:text="暂无+++++++++++++++
        +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        +++++++++++++++"/>
```

it will:

[image: this text show error, down dislocation]

the content don not show all, it will down dislocation.It like cause by the first TextView's minHeight attribute. But I don't down why?

Sorry, My english is very poor !

Comment: what the error please show me.

Comment: When the content too long, the TextView don't show all, it will down dislocation

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:gravity="center|start"
        android:minHeight="42dp"
        android:text="姓名" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:gravity="center|end"
        android:minHeight="42dp"
        android:text="暂无+++++++++++++++
    +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    +++++++++++++++" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank your votes~!

This way can make two childview keep align , but don not show the all content.

Comment: can u explain brief